# How do you format a cell in Google Sheets with quotation marks in the format?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how do you format cells' text to show as being wrapped in quotation marks (without needing to type in quotation marks as part of the data in the cell)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a custom number format to the cells (Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format) and enter `\“@\”`.

Quotation marks in that field [normally function as syntax characters](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=,custom-number-formatting) to specify text, so the `\` symbol is needed to treat them as literal quotation mark characters.